# accesing sqlite database using vb .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, sqlite

I am new to VB .net and working with SQLite.  I am not able to access Test1.db3, the code below simply creates a new file Test1.db3, therefore when I go to read the file I receive a response saying table 'Users' doesn't exist.  I am using VS Express 2013.

```vb
Sub Main()

    Dim Path As String = "J:\Location\SQLITE\"
    Dim dataBase As String = "test1.db"
    Dim cs As String = Path & dataBase
    Dim myConnection As New SQLiteConnection()
    Dim cadeomSQL As String = "Data Source=" & cs & ";"

    myConnection.ConnectionString = cadeomSQL
    myConnection.Open()

    Dim sSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM Users"
    Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(sSQL, myConnection)

        Dim rdr As SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        Using rdr
            While (rdr.Read())
                Console.WriteLine(rdr.GetString(0) & rdr.GetString(1) & rdr.GetString(2))
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
    myConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

Any advice will be much appreciated

Comment: I dont see your schema where you create the users table in sqllite db. You need to create the table before accessing it

Comment: Thanks qamar, The database and table already exist within the test.db.  I am simply trying to get information from it.  Is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dataBase As String = "test1.db"
    Dim Path As String = $"J:\Location\SQLITE\{dataBase}"
    Dim cadeomSQL As String = $"Data Source={Path};Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;"
    Dim myConnection As New SQLiteConnection()

    myConnection.ConnectionString = cadeomSQL
    myConnection.Open()

    Dim sSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM Users"
    Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(sSQL, myConnection)

        Dim rdr As SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        Using rdr
            While (rdr.Read())
                Console.WriteLine($"{rdr.Item(0)} {rdr.Item(1)} {rdr.Item(2)} {vbNewLine}")
            End While
        End Using

    End Using
    myConnection.Close()
End Sub
```